# In Android , How to populate data from xml linked to a certain activity java file to another xml file

Tags: android

I need to get values from views such as textview , imageview, integer variable those views are in xml file integrated to iys activity java file , i need these values to be added to recycler view but as objects with values

For example textview + textview + textview + imageview aligned horizontally to each others. And all these aligned views to be considered as one item in the recycler or list to be able to add as many lines as i need

To be honest i searched the web and tried a lot of tutorials handling listviews and recycles but failed .. .. thanks in advance

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Are you asking, how to design an item xml for recycler adapter?

Comment: Thanks for replying back to me but am asking about how to implement it . I mean. I need to fill a recyclerview by data from another xml file..

Comment: What is from another xml file(what data in xml file)?

Comment: Values from three textview s and one imageview

Comment: @Arnold Brown , I have tried a lot of methods and the one i think it will work is using a recyclerview and inside it i added a cardview then i added the needed textviews and imageview inside this cardview . And i can intent data from another activities to the desired one but i still not sure if the desired approach can be done or not

Comment: For my fellows whom asked me what i have tried to work this out.. I tried this as workaround but it is not the best practice however it still has issues .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48876223/i-need-to-intent-imageview-resource-file-that-is-originally-passed-from-another

Comment: Through intent what type of data are you passing ?.Did you receive the data at another end?

Comment: Amoung all your explanation you have to show some code snippet to show your issue even more clear...

Comment: Yes u received the String data but not the i.age one.. but this us just a workaround.